# Rails 4 - How to avoid undefined length for nil:Class before form is filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a system that allows users to select a series of symptoms and receive a list of all illnesses with those symptoms. I wish to display the form and the results in the same page for the sake of usability, but when the user access the search page it raises a `undefined method length for nil:NilClass` error pointing to my `illness.erb` scope (below).

This doesn't happen if the user accesses a page that already has a query, even if no symptoms match the query.

Scope:

```
scope :with_symptoms, ->(symptoms) { joins(illnesssymptoms: :symptom).where("symptoms.id in (?)", symptoms).group("illnesses.id")
                                        .having("count(illnesses.id) >= ?", symptoms.length) }
```

The error points specifically to

```
.having("count(illnesses.id) >= ?", symptoms.length) }
```

My index action (the one I'm using for searching) is like so:

```
def index
  @symptoms = Symptom.search(params[:search])

  @illnesses = Illness.with_symptoms(params[:symptom_ids])
end
```

This is the code that renders the illnesses:

```
 <% @illnesses.each do |illness| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to illness.name, illness %>: 
    <%= truncate(illness.description, :length => 100, :separator => ' ', :omission => '... (More)') %>
    <br />      <br />
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I tried putting the above between a `@illnesses.exists?` test but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a simple [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) statement here:

```
.having("count(illnesses.id) >= ?", symptoms.try(:length) || 0) }
```

(Thanks to markus for for `.try` method!)

That will evaluate to `0` if the symptoms array is nil or has no elements, and to the length of the array otherwise.

Comment: The answer code seems to lack one ) between the last ) and } (SO wouldn't let me edit since it's too short) and the error apparently persists with that change.
EDIT: it was a typing error on my end, your answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake. I'm not sure why you still get that error - let me take a look at this again.

Comment: Yes, perfectly. Thank you very much, scope is still something that somewhat confuses me due to its syntax

Comment: You can write it shorter the Rails way with `try`: `.having("count(illnesses.id) >= ?", symptoms.try(:length) || 0) }`

Comment: @markus Wonderful, I thought there was a better way to do this. Thank you!